# How to untangle the mess I made out of my GIT repository?

Tags: git, git-bash, smartgit

I'm super new to GIT, and thought I could create a simple test commit/push. In the process I ended up with a mess shown in the attached image.

[image]

The question is, what GIT commands do I need to invoke to remove all the stuff above the red arrow and leave origin/master at the point where the red arrow is?

I don't care about any files in my local clone of the repository. When this mess is fixed, I can just re-clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on your local version of master, I'd go with:

```
git reset --hard 4c5222c0
```

That brings your local repo to the hash of the commit pointed by the red arrow.

Then you can force push to master, for example like that:

```
git push origin +master
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways.

1. If you want to keep the files locally: `git reset 4c5222`
2. If you don't want to keep the files AT ALL `git reset --hard 4c5222`
3. If you want to keep the history and make a forward commit you can use `git revert COMMIT` for each commit that you want to remove.

Sounds like you want option 2 in this case, but it will completely removed any changes to files and is unrecoverable. So be sure. This will fix your master branch.

Now, to clean up the other branch you can simply delete the branch if you don't need anything on it. `git branch -D branch_name`